# What rights are needed to read all groups in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

So the question says it all. I am at a complete loss here, I have given the following rights to the app that manages users and can add/remove users from groups.

Here is the list of the rights I have given the app.

- User.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- GroupMember.Read.All
- User.ManageIdentities.All
- Group.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All

From what I understand I need only these:

- User.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The application itself is a SharePoint Webpart on SPFx 1.11 and the app itselt works prior I had many rights in the dev tenant and I removed them all to be sure the wp rights are sufficient to run the app, but no dice.

The insufficient rights issue occurs when I try to get all the groups from the `/groups` endpoint.

Comment: Is your app using delegated or application permissions? I am able to list groups with just Group.Read.All when added as an application permission.

Comment: @Danstan yes SPFx authenticates with the user's delegated premonitions, it causes all sorts of issues, but I never expected to need `User.Read` when I had `User.ReadWrite.All`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that I needed `User.Read` as well. If someone can answer why I needed those rights as well at the `/groups` endpoint that would be super helpful and I will accept that answer, but right now I needed these rights:

- User.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read